# copy all data in exists column to a new columns at Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvp

I have an exists data on database
NewMWU :

| id | data1 | data2 | data3 | measurementu | department_id | done_dep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | measurement1 | empty | default: 0 |

then I pass this data to some Departments Ids.
Controller :

```
    public function storeTS(Request $request)
{
    

    foreach( (array) $request->dep_ids as $dep_id ){

    $data = new NewMWU;
    $data->measurementu = $request->measurementu;
    $data->department_id =  $dep_id;
    $data->done_dep =  2;
    $data->save();        
}

Session::flash('success');
return redirect()->route('newMW.index');
```

After I passed data that will be like this on database at same table :
NewMWU :

| id | data1 | data2 | data3 | measurementu | department_id | done_dep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | measurement1 | empty | default: 0 |
| 2 | empty | empty | empty | measurement1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | empty | empty | empty | measurement1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | empty | empty | empty | measurement1 | 3 | 2 |

how can I copy data1,data2,data3 to a new columns that created with ids = 2,3,4 from column id = 1.

Blade page :

```
<form class="m-form m-form--fit" action="{{route('admin.newMW.storeTS')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

   <div id="divt" class="form-group m-form__group">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control m-input" name="measurementu"  required>
       <option value="">chose measurement</option> 
          @foreach ($measurement as $s)
          <option value="{{$s->measurementu}}">{{$s->measurementu}}</option>                                              
          @endforeach
      </select>
     </div>  
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="divt" class="m-form__group">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control m-input" name="dep_ids[]"  multiple required>
          @foreach ($mnue2 as $d)
          <option value="{{$d->id}}">{{$d->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>

                    
            <div class="m-portlet__foot m-portlet__foot--fit">
              <div class="m-form__actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>
              </div>
           </div>
     </form>
```

I tried a lot of thinks like I add inputs in blade page for data1,2,3 but that is does not work.

Hope to help me how can I pass data1,2,3 in column 1 to a new columns with a requested data.

Comment: You need to look up the data before the insert and build up your `$data` array appropriately. Or, pass _all the data_ with the form.

Comment: I tried to pass all data with form but its made a lot of mess like a duplicate data.. If you can give me an example to how can build Data array appropriately?

Comment: You want MySQL query or you want modify you function ?

Comment: Whatever will help to insert data to a new columns when i saved form, just give me any suggestion :)